# Show div based on div style 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a div which depends on the condition when div of some width is 100%. I want to show `.show_div` when width of `.main` div is 100%.

This is what I was trying to do:

```js
var x = $('.main');
if (x.width() == '100%' ) {
  $('.show_div').show();

}
```

```css
.main {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.show_div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" style="width:100%">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="show_div">
  I am visible bcz width 100%
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `100%` is incorrect syntax as you can see in the error the snippet creates.

Comment: @Art3mix still it is not working

Comment: @Art3mix `x.width()` return in `px` not `%`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you suggest how to write this in condition .. As I need the condition like that only as I have a progress bar which when will have style 100% width will show a div.

Comment: Get the full width at 100% in pixels, then compare the width to that as an integer value instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you please write an answer.

Comment: @SahilDhir Check my answer

Comment: @לבנימלכה my first comment was wrong, `x.width()` actually return a Number and not a String in `px`.

Comment: @Art3mix this number is string that means `px` not `%` (for eample `777` means `777px` and not `777%`)

Comment: @לבנימלכה Yes, but the actual value is a Number and not a string, you compare those differently, `x.width() == 777 OR x.width() == '777'` is correct but `x.width() == '777px'` is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use if `width` == `parent.width()` means `100%`

```js
 var x  = $('.main');

    if (x.width()== x.parent().width()){
        $('.show_div').show();

    }
```

```css
.main{  background: red; height: 50px; padding: 10px;}
    .show_div{ display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" style="width:100%">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="show_div">
I am visible bcz width 100%
</div>
```

You can do it in **css** if you use attribute `style` in DOM to declare `width`

```css
.main{  background: red; height: 50px; padding: 10px;}
.show_div{ display: none;}
.main[style="width:100%"]~.show_div{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main" style="width:100%">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="show_div">
    I am visible bcz width 100%
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for help

Comment: can you suggest how to write this in condition .. As I need the condition like that only as I have a progress bar which when will have style 100%  width or fill 100% will show a div.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use pure javascript here:

```
<div class="main" style="width:100%">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="show_div">
  I am visible bcz width 100%
</div>

var x = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];

if (x.style.width == '100%' ) {
  $('.show_div').show();

}
```

`x.width()` return the computed number in `px` of the selected div, so it doesn't check for 100%.

This answer is correct if you want to check the value of width property of the div is set to '100%' as you asked.

If you want to check if the computed width of the div is equal to the parent computed width you should see @לבנימלכה answer.